# Variables in Haskell

Tags: variables, haskell

Why does the following Haskell script not work as expected?

```
find :: Eq a => a -> [(a,b)] -> [b]
find k t = [v | (k,v) <- t]
```

Given `find 'b' [('a',1),('b',2),('c',3),('b',4)]`, the interpreter returns `[1,2,3,4]` instead of `[2,4]`. The introduction of a new variable, below called `u`, is necessary to get this to work:

```
find :: Eq a => a -> [(a,b)] -> [b]
find k t = [v | (u,v) <- t, k == u]
```

Does anyone know why the first variant does not produce the desired result?

Comment: Repeat after me: there are no variables in Haskell. ;-) These are symbols or identifiers. Variables imply variability. In Haskell, everything is immutable.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: The Haskell 98 Report uses the term "variable" all over the place. It's important to note that this doesn't mean what you might expect, but I don't think being more persnickety than the standard documentation is necessarily helpful.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Surely you jest! Why, I've found a whole section about variables [in some Haskell, right here](http://books.google.com/books?id=27dkTJFrLZIC&pg=PA111).

Comment: @Travis Brown: It means pretty much the same thing it does when speaking of variables bound by a quantifier in a formula of first-order logic... can't imagine why someone would expect anything else! ;)

Comment: Reading the first version of find, I was actually expecting [1,2,3,4]... Must read the function name also.

Comment: Huh. I never knew. In my defense, other languages do make the distinction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [Haskell 98 Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#list-comprehensions):

> As usual, bindings in list
>   comprehensions can shadow those in
>   outer scopes; for example:
>
> `[ x | x <- x, x <- x ]  =   [ z | y <- x, z <- y]`

One other point: if you compile with `-Wall` (or specifically with [`-fwarn-name-shadowing`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html)) you'll get the following warning:

```
Warning: This binding for `k' shadows the existing binding
           bound at Shadowing.hs:4:5
```

Using `-Wall` is usually a good idea—it will often highlight what's going on in potentially confusing situations like this.

Comment: I think the issue is not about shadowing. It's about the meaning of an identifier in a pattern in the first place -- that it does not match the value of a variable with that identifier, but rather matches anything and binds the value to a new variable with that idenfier

Answer (score 11):

The pattern match `(k,v) <- t` in the first example creates two new local variables `v` and `k` that are populated with the contents of the tuple `t`. The pattern match doesn't compare the contents of `t` against the already existing variable `k`, it creates a new variable `k` (which hides the outer one).

Generally there is never any "variable substitution" happening in a pattern, any variable names in a pattern always create new local variables.

Answer (score 3):

You can only pattern match on literals and constructors.
You can't match on variables. 
Read more [here](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html).

That being said, you may be interested in view patterns.