# Calling function in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm pretty new in Haskell programming. I want to call some functions and save the result in a variable but I don't know how. I read couple of chapters about haskell function in two different book but still don't understand how to do it.

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as M hiding (Map)

newtype GenEnv elt = Env (Map Id elt)

newEnv :: GenEnv elt                             -- initialise
newEnv = Env M.empty
newtype GenEnv elt = Env (Map Id elt)

newEnv :: GenEnv elt                             -- initialise
newEnv = Env M.empty

getEnv :: GenEnv elt -> Id -> Maybe elt          -- G(x) (key function)
getEnv (Env env) var = M.lookup var env

union  :: GenEnv elt -> (Id,elt) -> GenEnv elt    -- G[x:v]
union  (Env env) (key,elt) = Env (M.insert key elt env)

-- foldr is faster than addToFM_list!
unionL :: GenEnv elt -> [(Id,elt)] -> GenEnv elt -- list union
unionL (Env env) pairs  = Env $ foldr (\(k,e) g -> M.insert k e g) env pairs
```

What I'm asking here is NOT for somebody to do my work, asking how to call the functions because I don't understand their signature.

Comment: Looks like `GenEnv` and `newEnv` are declared twise. Is it a typo?

Comment: `fans` I think people need a bit more help figuring out what you are ultimately aiming at. I wonder if you see all these functions like `update` `filter` `insert` etc. that take you from one Map to another, and wonder, but how do I build up a Map to begin with? How do I get to the point of using these functions?  If that's the problem, then there are a number of answers, but the simple-minded answer is by using `fromList` `fromAscList` etc. You start with a list, e.g. of key value pairs, use `fromList`, engage in fancy Data.Map manipulations, then return to list-land with `toList` and co.

Comment: my question basically is, if I want to build a new map insert some data in it and then retrieve them. how to do that using the above functions. I came from java background and this is my first time to be exposed to functional programming.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, "variable" is perhaps not the right term. And in the same vein, "calling" a function is perhaps not the right term either. It is helpful, in my opinion, to think about this in terms of mathematical functions:

```
f(x) = x^2
```

given the above function, you don't "call" it with a value so much as give a name to the result of evaluating that function at a particular argument:

```
y = f(2)
```

It's the same in Haskell. Somewhere in your code you need to use the result of evaluating a function at a particular value. To do that, you can just use the application of that function to that value wherever you need it, or you can bind it to a name in a `let` binding or a `where` clause.

So, to provide a simple example in Haskell, you can do something like this:

```
f :: Int -> Int
f x = x^2

y :: Int
y = f 2

g :: Int -> Int
g x = let y = f 3
      in y + 1

h :: Int -> Int
h x = y + 1
        where y = f 3
```

Here I have declared a function called `f` which takes a single `Int` value and returns a new `Int` value, the square of the argument. Then I have declared an `Int` value named `y` to be the result of applying `f` to `2`. The value `y` is not a variable, but rather a binding. It will always be `4`.

Then I have declared two other functions, `g` and `h` which are equivalent, showing local bindings of the results of applying `f`.

In your example, the types are perhaps complicating things a little bit. `Env` is a constructor used to construct a value of the `Genenv` type. So, to create a value that is a `Genenv` type, you apply `Env` to an appropriate argument. This is what `newEnv` is doing.

Hopefully that's enough to get you started.

Comment: What I'm aiming to is to create new environment, map, insert values in it and them from time to time check if some key are in it or not. however I can not make sense of the syntax of how to interact with the functions above.

Comment: first thanks for replying, I wanted to ask is  (Id,elt)  a tuble?

Answer (score 1):

Since I pretty much suck at explaining these things, I'd recomment reading this chapter

http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/types-and-functions.html

should cover everything you need to know to be able to call those functions.

In general in Haskell we apply a function to some arguments and bind the results to some value.

Answer (score 0):

Haskell doesn't have variables, first of all. Generally we talk of binding an expression to an identifier, creating a thunk.

It has the form of

```
let val = unionEl g l
in --expression using val
```

Comment: To quote [myself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053789/variables-in-haskell): "The Haskell 98 Report uses the term 'variable' [all over the place](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sect3.2). It's important to note that this doesn't mean what you might expect, but I don't think being more persnickety than the standard documentation is necessarily helpful."

Comment: Actually, Haskell's variables are [just like variables in mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(mathematics)).

Comment: I'm meaning variables in the typical sense.

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell, function application is done through juxtaposition, but you can use parentheses first to get the feel for it, just don't use commas to separate parameters like you may be used to in other languages.

For instance, assuming Id is just a type synonym for Int, then the following would be an example GenEnv.

```
example :: GenEnv Char 
example = union newEnv (1, 'a')
```

which is the same as

```
example :: GenEnv Char 
example = union(newEnv (1, 'a'))
```

Say you have a list of the alphabet, associated with an integer value, called `alphabetKeys`, you can use the handy little tool you defined to turn that into a GenEnv pretty easily, just by

```
example :: GenEnv Char
example = union newEnv alphabetKeys
```

again,

```
 example :: GenEnv Char 
 example = union(newEnv alphabetKeys)
```

would work just as well.